# How to select UIImageView with name of Object

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimageview

I added 6 UIImageViews in Interface Builder.
Those are declared.

> @property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIImageView *Image1;
>
> @property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIImageView *Image2;
>
> @property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIImageView *Image3;
>
> @property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIImageView *Image4;
>
> @property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIImageView *Image5;
>
> @property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIImageView *Image6;

Those UIImageView' name has a rule - "Image" + number.

I want to select those ImageViews dinamically.
For example,

> for (NSInteger i = 0; i < 6 ; i++) {
>
> ```
>     if(... condition ) 
>     {
>        //new 
>        [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Image%d", i+1] setHidden:YES];  //--(1) 
>     }
>     else
>     {
>         [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Image%d", i+1] setHidden:NO];  //--(2) 
>     }
>
> }
> ```

But, this code isn't correct. 
Please tell me more good way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jonkroll's suggestion to put your image views in an array is a good way to do it, and generally the highest performance.

Another way is to use key-value coding (KVC) to access your properties by name:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 6; ++i) {
    NSString *key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Image%d", i + 1];
    UIImageView *imageView = (UIImageView *)[self valueForKey:key];
    imageView.hidden = condition;
}
```

Using the view tag, as Mark suggests, is a third way to do it.  His answer is a little short on details, so I will provide some.

You can set the tag in your nib:

[image: Interface Builder with tag field circled]

So you can set the tag of your `Image1` image view to 1, and the tag of your `Image2` image view to 2, and so on.

Then you can find an image view by its tag using the `viewWithTag:` method on your top-level view:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 6; ++i) {
    [self.view viewWithTag:i+1].hidden = condition;
}
```

Comment: I liked the first way, Key-Value coding. Good one Rob :)

Answer (score 1):

Create an array of your imageViews and iterate over them using fast enumeration:

```
NSArray *imageViewArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:self.Image1,self.Image2,self.Image3,self.Image4,self.Image5,self.Image6,nil];

for (UIImageView* imageView in imageViewArray) {

    if(... condition ) {
       [imageView setHidden:YES];  //--(1) 
    } else {
        [imageView setHidden:NO];  //--(2) 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

typically you can use Tag to identify your views, instead of using the name of the view.

@property(nonatomic) NSInteger tag

see here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html

once you've set the tag, you can then do things like 
if(uiview.tag == kSomeButtonTag)